# SetTimeout to populate Javascript Object while a function looped AJAX requests to get data

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, asynchronous, ajax

I wrote some code that will get the name and data of a node or multiple of nodes and put them in an object (seriesData) so I can use said object for a chart (renderChart). I used setTimeout() so seriesData can populate before rendering the chart.

Everything works as intended. Is there a better pattern to handle this? I read up on Promises but am not sure how to implement in a looped AJAX within getData() or is even needed.

```
const seriesData = {
    name: [],
    data: [],
};

function getNodeList() {
    let nodeList = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/masternode',
        success: function (result) {
            let nodes = $(result).find('ID');
            let addresses = $(result).find('Address');
            for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                let node = $(nodes[i]).text();
                let address = $(addresses[i]).text();
                nodeList.push({ node: node, address: address });
            }
            getData(nodeList, seriesData);
            setTimeout(renderChart, 50);
        },
    });
}

function getData(nodeList, seriesData) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
        let ipAddress = nodeList[i].address;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/' + ipAddress,
            success: function (result) {
                let sData = $(result).find('Data').text();
                seriesData.name.push(ipAddress);
                seriesData.data.push(sData);
            },
        });
    }
}

// Omitted chart options
// ...


function renderChart() {
    chart.render();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Are you sure it works as intended? are the requests going to a nearby/local server? One could call `renderChart()` within the `success` handler within `getData()` when `i` matches `nodeList.length - 1`... though there is no guarantee that all of the requests will complete in sequential order unless [`async: false` is added to the requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450813/1575353)

Comment: The request is going to a nearby server. If I change the `SetTimeout` lower than `50`, it won't render the data it was pushed by `getData` function. I haven't thought about changing the `async` flag, I haven't define it.

Comment: Because I would prefer to not assume, is `$.ajax()` the [jquery method `jQuery.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or does it come from another library?

Comment: `$.ajax()` is `jQuery.ajax()`. I do appreciate you commenting on this. This helped me look at the code from another perspective. I have changed the code quite a bit and utilized `jQuery.ajax()` async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Initial Review thoughts

Before addressing the main question I’d like to address a few points first.

### Variable declaration style

It is nice that `seriesData` is declared with `const`, since it never gets reassigned. Some variables within the functions like `nodeList`, `nodes`, `addresses` and `ipAddress` also are never reassigned so they could also be declared with `const`. This helps avoid [accidental re-assignment and other bugs](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/278653/244085).

### ES-6 Object declaration

The object pushed into `nodeList` in the loop uses plain object syntax:

> ```
> nodeList.push({ node: node, address: address });
> ```

The [shorthand property definition notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions) can be used to eliminate the keys, since they are the same name as the variables used for the values:

```
 nodeList.push({ node, address });
```

### Single use variables

The variable `ipAddress` is only used once. Instead of

> ```
> url: '/' + ipAddress,
> ```

unless that variable was used for debugging, it can be eliminated:

```
url: '/' + nodeList[i].address,
```

The same is true for `node` and `addressed`, but if those were eliminated then the ES-6 shorthand syntax could not be utilized.

## Main Question

The main question posed here is “*Is there a better pattern to handle this?*”

I would first ask if the API supports returning data for multiple nodes in a single endpoint. If this was possible then there would be no need to make multiple requests, improving network efficiency and eliminating the risk of network connection issues, service interruptions for others, etc.

One could ask a question like “*How to know when all the ajax calls in a loop are completed?*”

And there are similar questions asked on stack overflow - for example: [*How to know when all the ajax calls in JQuery each loop are completed?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38680677/1575353). As the accepted answer suggests, the jQuery utility function [`jQuery.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/#jQuery-when-deferreds) can be used to execute a callback function when promises are completed.

Note that [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a [`jqXHR` object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) and

> The jqXHR objects returned by `$.ajax()` as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise (see [Deferred object](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information).

By putting the return values from calling `$.ajax()` into an array, that array can be passed in a call to [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/#jQuery-when-deferreds) so `renderChart()` can then be called after all of the requests have completed.

See the example below for a demonstration. It uses the convenience method [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) instead of `$.ajax()` to skip passing `type: 'GET',`. As the log may show- the requests often finish in an order that is not sequential.

```js
const seriesData = {
  name: [],
  data: [],
};
let count = 0;
const progressBar = $('progress');

function getNodeList() {
  $('#log').append($('<div>').html(`fetching list of ships from API`));
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/',
    success: function(ships) {
      if ((typeof ships !== 'object') || !ships.hasOwnProperty('results')) {
        console.error('invalid response', ships)
        return;
      }
      progressBar.val(++count);
      $('#log').append($('<div>').html(`got list of ships from API`));
      getData(ships.results.slice(0, 5).map(ship => ship.url), seriesData);
    },
  });
}

function getData(nodeList, seriesData) {
  const promises = nodeList.map((url, i) =>
    $.get({
      url,
      success: function(ship) {
        seriesData.name.push(ship.name);
        seriesData.data.push(ship.length);
        progressBar.val(++count);
        $('#log').append($('<div>').html(`${i+1} added ${ship.name} with length: ${ship.length}m`));
      },
    })
  );
  $.when(...promises).then(function(result) {
    renderChart();
  });
}

// Omitted chart options
// ...

getNodeList()

function renderChart() {
  Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
  const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: seriesData.name,
      datasets: [{
        data: seriesData.data,
        label: 'Ship Length',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderColor: 'green',
        fill: false
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Ship Lengths'
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Ship'
          }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: true,
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Length (meters)'
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  };
  const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

```css
#loading_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
#loading_container  > progress {
  flex: auto;
}
#loading_container > span {
  width: 9rem;
}
#log {
  font-size: x-small;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.chartjs.org/dist/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="//www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading_container">
  <span>Loading Progress:</span>
  <progress max="6" value="0"></progress>
</div>
<span id="log"></span>
<div>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

If one wasn't using jQuery, the generic method [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) could be used to execute a callback when promises are completed.